# Referencing subqueries for SQL

Tags: sql

I'd like to create a SQL subquery something like

```
(select * 
from table t
where abc is true) as query_one; 

select * 
from query_one
group by abc
```

However, I keep running into syntax errors with trying to alias query_one... what's the right way to do this?

Comment: `create view query_one as select ...`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CTE:

```
with query_one as (
      select * 
      from table t
      where abc is true
     )
select abc, count(*)
from query_one
group by abc;
```

Note that `select *` and `group by` do not belong together.  This should be generating a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're trying to create a view:

```sql
CREATE VIEW query_one AS
SELECT *
FROM   t
WHERE  abc = true
```

Comment: I did that but I'm now getting No results were returned by the query when I do a select * over the view... do you know what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select *  from
          (select * 
            from table t
              where abc is true) query_one
    group by abc
```